# Navigation to a previous tabbed page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, tabbedpage

I asked a similar question yesterday but I've tried out some new techniques, and am looking for further advice:

I currently have a tabbed iOS xamarin forms application like so:

```
 <TabbedPage>
     <local:UploadPage Title="Upload" IconImageSource="upload.png"/>
     <NavigationPage Title="Camera" IconImageSource="camera2.png">
         <x:Arguments>
             <local:CameraPage />
         </x:Arguments>
     </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

I'd like to be able to click the camera tab, take a picture, and then the app will automatically go back to the "upload" tab upon exiting the camera.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

I've tried using:  await Navigation.PushAsync(new UploadPage()); but this just pushed a new page onto the "camera" tab - what im really wanting is to somehow return control back to the first tab called "upload".

I uploaded a gif of what it is I'm wanting - just pretend that at the end of the gif instead of manually clicking the first tab, ideally the app would automatically take you there

[image]

Any idea on how to accomplish this? any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried setting the current page like so:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new UploadPage();
```

However this causes my tab bar at the bottom of the screen to disappear, and i can only see the one page i pushed to the stack, without access to my 2 tabs.

Comment: set the TabbedPage's CurrentPage property

Comment: @Jason I just edited my question to include my issues with doing that. What else could i try?

Comment: your edit has nothing to do with what I suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `TabbedPage`'s `CurrentPage` property

```
var tab = (TabbedPage)Application.Current.MainPage;
tab.CurrentPage = tab.Children[0];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I apologize for not understanding your first suggestion- I thought my edit was changing the current page property. How did you know to do this? I had a hard time finding documentation that detailed this syntax. I appreciate your help.

Comment: scan the API docs for the TabbedPage until you find a property or method that seems to do what you need